# How can I modify this Perl subroutine so that it prints the contents of the file, using print_file?

Tags: perl, scripting

Reading *Learning Perl the Hard Way* by Allen B. Downey.

Exercise 1.1 says:

> The glob operator takes a pattern as an argument and returns a list
> of all the files that match the given pattern. A common use of glob is to list the files
> in a directory.
>
> `my @files = glob "$dir/*";`
>
> The pattern `$dir/*` means “all the files in the directory whose name is stored in `$dir`”.
> See the documentation of glob for examples of other patterns.
> Write a subroutine called print dir that takes the name of a directory as a parameter
> and that prints the file in that directory, one per line.

I did that:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

sub print_dir {

        my $dir = shift;

        my @files = glob "$dir/*";

        foreach my $file (@files) {

                print "$file\n";
        }

}

print_dir @ARGV;
```

Then Exercise 1.2 says 'Modify the previous subroutine so that instead of printing the name
of the file, it prints the contents of the file, using print_file.'

I'm struggling with this one. I have a script that prints the contents of a file:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

sub print_file {
        my $file = shift;
        open(my $FILE, $file) 
             or die $!;
        while (my $line = <$FILE>) {
                print $line;
        }
}

sub cat {
        foreach my $file (@_) {
                print_file $file;
        }
}

cat @ARGV;
```

And then I have the other script above that prints the names of all files in a directory. So this is what I have so far trying to get all files in a directory and then print the contents of all of those files:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

sub print_file {
        my $file = shift;
        open(my $FILE, $file)
             or die $!;
        while (my $line = <$FILE>) {
                print $line;
        }
}

sub print_dir {
        my $dir = shift;
        my @files = glob "$dir/*";

        while (my $dir = shift)   {
                foreach my $file (@files) {
                        print_file "$file";
                }
        }
}

print_dir @ARGV;
```

And obviously it's not working and there is no error message either.

Comment: You add a line feed to the file name for no reason. `"$file\n"` should be `$file`.

Comment: Note: for code sanity if file was open, once it used file handler should be closed (perl will do it for you, although for clean code the filehandle should be closed anyway).

Comment: Note: in last code sample `while (my $dir = shift)` perhaps will return what you have not intended to receive (you  already shifted argument at entrance into subroutine).

Comment: Note: if you intend to `print $var . "\n"` then perl provides an alternative [say $var](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/say) what simplifies code readability.

Answer (score 2):

You add a line feed to the file name for no reason.

```perl
print_file "$file\n";
```

should be

```perl
print_file $file;
```

---

By the way, it's a bad practice to use global vars (like `FILE`) for nothing. And it's a good idea to check `open` for errors as it's quite prone to them.

```perl
open my $FILE, $file
   or die "Can't open \"$file\": $!\n";

while (my $line = <$FILE>) {
   ...
}
```

With your bug, this would have output something like

```
Can't open "./some_file
": No such file or directory
```

Answer (score -1):

Following code snippets demonstrate two possible solutions to your exercises.

Perl code can be very concise in expression of desired algorithm (principle of:
brevity is the soul of wit).

Note 1: code verifies that passed argument is a directory

Note 2: code skips the output of *content of directory* as it is not a file

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

print_dir($_) for @ARGV;

sub print_dir {
    my $dir = shift;
    
    die "$dir isn't a directory" unless -d $dir;
    
    say for glob("$dir/*");
}
```

Modified code to print content of the files

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

print_dir($_) for @ARGV;

sub print_dir {
    my $dir = shift;

    die "$dir isn't a directory" unless -d $dir;
    
    for my $fname ( glob("$dir/*") ) {
        next if -d $fname;             # skip directories
        say "\n" . '-' x 25 
          . "\n" . $fname 
          . "\n" . '-' x 25;
        open my $fh, '<', $fname
            or die "Couldn't open $fname";
        print while <$fh>;
        close $fh;
    }
}
```

Reference:

- [-X file test](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/-X)
- [glob](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/glob)
- [open](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open)
- [die](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/die)
- [say](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/say)
- [perlvar](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar)
- Tutorial: [Perl file test operators](https://www.perltutorial.org/perl-file-test-operators/)
- Tutorial: [Perl special variables](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/perl/perl_special_variables.htm)

Recomendation:

- [Learn Perl](https://learn.perl.org/)
- [Perl Documentation](https://perldoc.perl.org/)
- [Perl Library](https://www.perl.org/books/library.html)
- [Free Perl Books](https://www.google.com/search?q=free+perl+books)